# Create a one to many socket pipe in linux

Tags: linux, sockets

We have a solution that consists of several executables, one of which is a "service" that just opens up a socket and whenever it receives data, we output it to a vector of other sockets, basically creating a one to many pipe between the sockets. Due to security reasons, I can't share the code itself but it is really simple and naïve and has a lot of problems just as it sounds.
I'll also note, that we keep the connection data of all the sockets in a configuration file, which is a requirement.

Now, recently we were tasked with porting our solution to a Linux environment, so I thought this would be a great opportunity to implement a better solution to this, "IP Broker" which is how this server is called. Instead of just compiling the same C++ code on a Linux machine and deal with the same problems.

I've tried looking for a way to pipe two sockets but came out empty, I know that systemd has a socket unit, but it looks like the only thing it does is run a service unit if a socket actually gets data (which I may use as well to save CPU time).

My question is, is there a tool that can do this for us on a Linux machine?

Edit:

Here is some pusedocode to get a feeling of what is happening in the "service":

```
Socket receiveSocket  = new Socket(strRcvSocket, strRcvPort)

vector<Socket> sendSockets = new vector<Socket>();
for(int i = 0; i < strSendSocketList.len(); i++)
{
    Socket sendSocket = new Socket(strSendSocketList[i], strRcvPortList[i])
    sendSockets.push_back(sendSocket);
}

int readBytes = 0;
char buffer[256];
while (1)
{
    readBytes = read(receiveSocket, buffer, 256); 
    
    if( readBytes > 0 )
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sendSockets.len(); i++)
        {
            write(sendSockets[i], buffer, readBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to answer the question. A single listening socket can of course handle multiple connections (by spawning new sockets via the `accept()` call); this is how every common network server works. It's not clear how what you're doing is any different. You don't need to show us your *actual* code, but you should create a minimal example that demonstrates how you're trying to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi @larsks , thanks for replying! I've added some psuedocode to help get a feeling of what we are doing there, but I'd like to add, at this stage, I would like to avoid rewriting the code itself, if it comes to that, then we will create a totally new design, introduce threads, etc. I was thinking that just as I would use Wireshark instead of creating new SW to monitor traffic, there might be a tool that already does something like that.

Comment: Well, _a tool that can do this for us on a Linux machine_ is `tee` in a shell which supports socket I/O redirection.

Comment: Thank you @Armali! I think this is exactly what I was looking for, I'll test this in the next few days and edit the original post with my findings!